# The algorithm behind pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, outliers, threshold, noise

I am investigating how a particular statistical outlier removal algorithm of 3D data works, but I am not able to properly figure out what they are doing.

The purpose of this algorithm, is to removal outlier points (in 3D space), and this algorithm is parameterized by `k`, which is the number of neighbors each points considers, and an `std_threshold` which seems to be a threshold on some standard deviation.

[This explanation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php) seems to be especially obtuse, where they claim it works by:

> Our sparse outlier removal is based on the computation of the
>   distribution of point to neighbors distances in the input dataset. For
>   each point, we compute the mean distance from it to all its neighbors.
>   By assuming that the resulted distribution is Gaussian with a mean and
>   a standard deviation, all points whose mean distances are outside an
>   interval defined by the global distances mean and standard deviation
>   can be considered as outliers and trimmed from the dataset.

[This explanation](http://www.jeffdelmerico.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/pcl_tutorial.pdf) on the other hand claims that this algorithm works by:

> Filtering points based on their local point densities, by removing points
>   that are sparse relative to the mean point density of the whole cloud.

I am trying to attain a somewhat formalized explanation of this technique. I understand the intuition behind it, but I cannot seem to reconcile exactly what they are doing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Surprisingly the algorithm isn't very complicated and the explanation on the [pcl website](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php) is actually almost all there is to it.
There's however some subtleties that don't appear in the above link, so here is a break down for more details.

- Set k, an integer, representing the number of closest points around point $P_i$ (parameter `setMeanK` in `pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval`).
- Set a standard deviation multiplier $\alpha$ (parameter `setStddevMulThresh`)
- For every point $P_i$ in the 3D point cloud.

  - Find the location of the $k$ nearest neighbors to point $P_i$ (their indexes in the cloud)
  - Compute the average distance $d_i$ from point $P_i$ to its $k$ nearest neighbors.
- Compute the mean $\mu_d$ of the distances $d_i$
- Compute the standard deviation $\sigma_d$ of the distances $d_i$
- Compute the threshold $T = \mu_d + \alpha \cdot \sigma_d$
- Eliminate points in the cloud for which the average distance to its $k$ neighbours is at a distance $d > T$

The implementation therefore requires two passes over the whole set of points in the cloud:

1. First pass to compute the mean and standard deviation of the distances from each points in the cloud to their $k$ nearest neighbours
2. Second pass to eliminate all the points in the cloud which mean distance (computed in the first pass) is higher than the threshold defined above.

$Notes$:

1) While the algorithm will in effect eliminate points which distance to its $k$ nearest neighbors follows any statistical distribution, its parameters $\mu$ and $ \sigma$ are only meaningful for a normal (Gaussian) distribution.

2) the algorithm assumes the capability to obtain the k nearest neighbors of any given point in the point cloud.

Comment: So..., If I take a lower stddev_multiplier, I will reduce the (single, globally valid) T, thus making point removal more aggressive. Also, mean_k should not be selected larger than the smallest expected clusters?